# Having trouble getting the test to my school work to run without an error

Tags: c#

I'm working on school work and have been stuck for a couple days now. Not even looking for someone to do it for me, just looking for a direction to be pointed in. I'm given a date (Date(1, 1, 2014)) and I have to get the function to return the offset of that month. I don't know how to link my Date constructor to the enums I made for previous tests or if that's even what I'm supposed to do. Here are a couple test that have passed leading up to the current one.

```
// Find the name of a day of the week
[TestMethod]
public void GetDayNameFromEnum()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("Sunday", Date.DayOfWeek.Sunday.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("Monday", Date.DayOfWeek.Monday.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("Tuesday", Date.DayOfWeek.Tuesday.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("Wednesday", Date.DayOfWeek.Wednesday.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("Thursday", Date.DayOfWeek.Thursday.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("Friday", Date.DayOfWeek.Friday.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("Saturday", Date.DayOfWeek.Saturday.ToString());
}

// Get a month name from the enum
[TestMethod]
public void MonthNameFromEnum()
{
    Assert.AreEqual("January", Date.MonthName.January.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("February", Date.MonthName.February.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("March", Date.MonthName.March.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("April", Date.MonthName.April.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("May", Date.MonthName.May.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("June", Date.MonthName.June.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("July", Date.MonthName.July.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("August", Date.MonthName.August.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("September", Date.MonthName.September.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("October", Date.MonthName.October.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("November", Date.MonthName.November.ToString());
    Assert.AreEqual("December", Date.MonthName.December.ToString());
}

// Find the start day for each month
[TestMethod]
public void TestMonthOffsetEnums()
{
    Assert.AreEqual(0, (int)Date.Offset.January);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, (int)Date.Offset.February);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, (int)Date.Offset.March);
    Assert.AreEqual(6, (int)Date.Offset.April);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, (int)Date.Offset.May);
    Assert.AreEqual(4, (int)Date.Offset.June);
    Assert.AreEqual(6, (int)Date.Offset.July);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, (int)Date.Offset.August);
    Assert.AreEqual(5, (int)Date.Offset.September);
    Assert.AreEqual(0, (int)Date.Offset.October);
    Assert.AreEqual(3, (int)Date.Offset.November);
    Assert.AreEqual(5, (int)Date.Offset.December);
}

// Find the month offset for a given date
[TestMethod]
public void GetMonthOffsetForSpecifiedDate()
{
    Date janDate = new Date(1, 1, 2014);
    Assert.AreEqual(Date.Offset.January, janDate.GetMonthOffset());

    Date junDate = new Date(6, 16, 2014);
    Assert.AreEqual(Date.Offset.June, junDate.GetMonthOffset());

    Date decDate = new Date(12, 12, 2014);
    Assert.AreEqual(Date.Offset.December, decDate.GetMonthOffset());
}
```

This is what my Date class is currently. The Last test is saying the AreEqual for janDate failed because it was expecting October but got May. But from my understanding it's not supposed to get either of those Months. I'm not sure I'm understanding exactly what I'm supposed to be doing here.

```
public class Date
{
    public int Day {  get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }  
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public Date(int month, int day, int year) 
    {   
        Day = day;
        Month = month;
        Year = year;
    }

    public enum DayOfWeek { Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday }

    public enum MonthName { January = 1, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December }

    public enum Offset { January = 0, February = 3, March = 3, April = 6, May = 1, June = 4, July = 6, August = 2, September = 5, October = 0, November = 3, December = 5 }

    public Offset GetMonthOffset()
    {

        return (Offset) Month;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I applaud you for not looking for someone to do your homework for you. At the heart of the problem is a simple bug in your code.  I do not want to elaborate on other issues with your code because it is homework, but more importantly, your teacher may or may not want you to dig into certain features of C# or .NET just yet.

Your Month property and MonthName enum are 1-based.  January == 1.

The Offset enum for January has a value of 0.  This is the disconnect of your code.  HINT: You may want to try changing GetMonthOffset to account for this.

If your class has already learned about Dictionary objects, you may consider changing the Offset enum to be a Dictionary<int, int>.  Instead of an enum, it could be a static property named MonthOffset.  The int Key would be the 1-based Month (to match the Month property), and the int Value would be the offset.  DO NOT EXPLORE THIS CODING IF YOUR TEACHER HAS NOT TAUGHT ABOUT DICTIONARIES.

Answer (score 0):

If you have e.g. `Month` = 4 (i.e., April), and write `(Offset)Month`, this returns you the `Offset` enum value having the number 4, which is the offset of `June`.

Therefore, your approach doesn't work.

A possible approach is to store the offsets in an array where the array index is the month number. Since no month is numbered 0, the first array entry will remain unused.

```cs
private static readonly Offset[] _monthOffset = [
    0, 
    Offset.January,
    Offset.February,
    Offset.March,
    Offset.April,
    Offset.May,
    Offset.June,
    Offset.July,
    Offset.August,
    Offset.September,
    Offset.October,
    Offset.November,
    Offset.December
];

public Offset GetMonthOffset()
{
    return _monthOffset[Month];
}
```

I made the array `static`, so that every instance of your `Date` class can share the same array (there is no need to make a copy of it for each date).